# How can i maintain different query files for different countries in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am working on a multi-country application where I have different db schemas for each country. I want to understand how can i call a different query file based on the country a user belongs to.. One way i thought of was maintaining different query files for different countries (IqueryConstantsIndia, IQueryConstntChina etc) and to check the country of the user in the constructor of the repository class and then call the query file based on the same but how do i return a class name is what i am stuck with.. Can anyone help on this or if you think there is a better way of implementing this.

Comment: if the different database schemas you have only differ by the language they use, then your application design is wrong. Different languages should be handled by using different message files where each message file corresponds to a single language.

Comment: No the messages/language are same but the data for each country is to be maintained in separate tables.

Comment: one way to do it would be to use native queries (with the help of JdbcTemplate), where you would prepend a schema prefix to every table name (e.g "String nativeQuery = "select x, y from " + schemaPrefix + ".tableName "). This way you don't need multiple queries which differ only in the schema.